# merge two separate mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

need to merge (maybe UNION ALL) this two mysql queries..

```
select users.name as 'Agent', min(agent_activities.created_at) as 'Login Time' 
from agent_activities, users
where 
agent_activities.agent_id = users.id 
and date(agent_activities.created_at) = curdate() 
and agent_activities.activity='login' 
group by agent_activities.agent_id 
order by agent_activities.agent_id asc;

select users.name as 'Agent', max(agent_activities.created_at) as 'Logout Time' 
from agent_activities, users
where 
agent_activities.agent_id = users.id 
and date(agent_activities.created_at) = curdate() 
and agent_activities.activity='logout' 
group by agent_activities.agent_id 
order by agent_activities.agent_id asc;
```

Now result is

```
Agent       | Login Time
test Admin  | 2018-09-27 10:26:54
Agent 1     | 2018-09-27 11:43:44
Hari        |  2018-09-27 11:10:41

Agent       | Logout Time
test Admin  | 2018-09-27 11:43:41
Agent 1     | 2018-09-27 11:45:04
ttt         | 2018-09-27 11:21:06
Hari VH     | 2018-09-27 15:18:04
```

Desired result

```
Agent       | Login Time           | Logout Time
test Admin  | 2018-09-27 10:26:54  | 2018-09-27 11:43:41
Agent 1     | 2018-09-27 11:43:44  | 2018-09-27 11:45:04
Hari        |  2018-09-27 11:10:41 | 2018-09-27 15:18:04
```

Please help,..................................

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by merge ? `UNION ALL` ??

Comment: UNION ALL? maybe not sure

Comment: Why are you asking us rather than trying `UNION ALL` yourself? We can make inferences about the intent here - but you should be explaining how you want to present the data - do you want login times in the same row as logout times? If so how do you want to handle overlapping sessions? Why are you seeking too see all the data in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with conditional aggregation:

```
select users.name as 'Agent', min(case when agent_activities.activity='login' then agent_activities.created_at end) as 'Login Time' ,
max(case when agent_activities.activity='logout' then agent_activities.created_at end) as 'Logout Time'
from agent_activities inner join users
on agent_activities.agent_id = users.id 
and date(agent_activities.created_at) = curdate() 
group by users.name 
order by users.name asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select u.name as Agent,
       max(case when aa.activity = 'login' then aa.created_at end) as Login_Time,
       max(case when aa.activity = 'logout' then aa.created_at end) as Logout_Time 
from agent_activities aa join
     users u
     on aa.agent_id = u.id 
where aa.created_at >= curdate() and
      aa.created_at < curdate() + interval 1 day
group by u.name 
order by u.name  asc;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read. Use abbreviations for the table names.
- Using functions on columns generally impedes the use of indexes, so I replaced `date(created_at)` with simpler date comparisons.
- Your `GROUP BY` columns should match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I missed that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional min/max, and consider the min `created_at` only when the activity is `login`, and vice-versa for logout.  The reason this works is that the default `ELSE` value (not explicitly shown) is `NULL`, which is *ignored* by both `MIN` and `MAX`.

```
SELECT
    u.name as 'Agent',
    MIN(CASE WHEN a.activity = 'login'  THEN a.created_at END) AS 'Login Time' 
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.activity = 'logout' THEN a.created_at END) AS 'Logout Time' 
FROM agent_activities a
INNER JOIN users u
    ON a.agent_id = u.id 
WHERE
    DATE(a.created_at) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY
    a.agent_id, u.name
ORDER BY
    a.agent_id, u.name;
```

Some notes:

I converted your implicit join to an *explicit* inner join, with an `ON` clause.  Also, I introduced table aliases into the query, which leaves it much easier to read.